# Currently having merge sort logical error with a array of objects

Tags: java, mergesort

I'm currently trying to merge sort an array of objects using the `compareTo` method in the `Box` class. I think I have it down but I'm getting this logical error.
Sorting the array using *merge sort*.
The array after merge sort:

```
Width: 67.8 height: 41.5    length: 56.1    Volume: 157848.57
Width: 67.8 height: 41.5    length: 56.1    Volume: 157848.57
Width: 67.8 height: 41.5    length: 56.1    Volume: 157848.57
Width: 67.8 height: 41.5    length: 56.1    Volume: 157848.57
Width: 67.8 height: 41.5    length: 56.1    Volume: 157848.57
Width: 67.8 height: 41.5    length: 56.1    Volume: 157848.57
Width: 67.8 height: 41.5    length: 56.1    Volume: 157848.57
Width: 67.8 height: 41.5    length: 56.1    Volume: 157848.57
Width: 67.8 height: 41.5    length: 56.1    Volume: 157848.57
Width: 67.8 height: 41.5    length: 56.1    Volume: 157848.57
```

It seems to only copy that one object. I do not know where I went wrong. I've tried changing the `compareTo` method logic but it seems to stay the same no matter what. Here is my merge sort method:

```java
static void mergeSort(Box[] theBoxes) {
    if(theBoxes.length > 1 ){
        Box [] firstHalf = new Box[theBoxes.length/2];
        System.arraycopy(theBoxes, 0 , firstHalf, 0 ,theBoxes.length /2); 
        mergeSort(firstHalf);
        //Merge sort the second half 
        int secondHalfLength = theBoxes.length - theBoxes.length / 2 ; 
        Box [] secondHalf = new Box [secondHalfLength];
        System.arraycopy(theBoxes, 0 , secondHalf, 0 ,secondHalfLength);
        mergeSort(secondHalf);

        merge(firstHalf, secondHalf , theBoxes); 
    }
}

static void merge(Box [] list1, Box [] list2 , Box [] temp ){
    int current1 = 0;
    int current2 = 0;
    int current3 = 0; 

    while (current1 < list1.length && current2 < list2.length){
        if(list1[current1].compareTo(list2[current2])> 0){ 
            temp[current3++] = list1[current1++];
        }else{
            temp[current3++] = list2[current2++];
        }

        while(current1 < list1.length){
            temp[current3++] = list1[current1++];
        }
        while(current2 < list2.length){
            temp[current3++] = list2[current2++];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `Box` class:

```java
public class Box {
  private double width, height, length;
  
  Box(double w, double h, double l){
    width=w;
    height=h;
    length=l;
  }
  
  private double getVolume(){
    return width*height*length;
  }
    
  public int compareTo(Box o){
    double myVol = this.getVolume();
    double thatVol = o.getVolume();
    if (myVol>thatVol)
      return 1;
    else if (myVol<thatVol)
      return -1;
    else
      return 0;
  }
  
  public String toString(){
    return "Width: "+width+
           "\theight: "+height+
            "\tlength: "+length+
            "\tVolume: "+getVolume();
  }
}
```

I am not allowed to change the `Box` class.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe, you are not passing correct parameter while copying your *arrays* data to *secondary* array for sorting purpose.

```
static Box [] arrayCopy(Box [] box, int left, int right) {
    Box [] tempArray = new Box[right - left];
    for(int i=left, m=0; i<right; i++, m++) {
        tempArray[m] = box[i];
    }
    return tempArray;
}
static void mergeSort(Box[] theBoxes) {
    if (theBoxes.length > 1) {
        //Box[] firstHalf = new Box[theBoxes.length / 2];
        //System.arraycopy(theBoxes, 0, firstHalf, 0, theBoxes.length / 2);
        Box [] firstHalf = arrayCopy(theBoxes, 0, theBoxes.length/2);
        mergeSort(firstHalf);
        // Merge sort the second half
        //int secondHalfLength = theBoxes.length - theBoxes.length / 2;
        //Box[] secondHalf = new Box[secondHalfLength];
        //System.arraycopy(theBoxes, 0, secondHalf, 0, secondHalfLength);
        
        Box [] secondHalf = arrayCopy(theBoxes, theBoxes.length/2, theBoxes.length);
        mergeSort(secondHalf);

        merge(firstHalf, secondHalf, theBoxes);
    }
}
```

Please note - I DO not know how `System.arraycopy` works in Java, therefore I wrote my own copy algorithm and it seems worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```java
Box[] firstHalf = new Box[theBoxes.length/2];
```

This is only correct if the number of elements in `theBoxes` is even.

If `theBoxes` contains 7 (seven) elements, for example, then `theBoxes.length / 2` returns 3 (three) – since you are doing integer division. This means that `firstHalf` will contain three elements. Hence `secondHalf` needs to contain 4 (four) elements. So your code for dividing `theBoxes` into two halves is incorrect. I propose the following for dividing `theBoxes`:

```java
int mid = theBoxes.length / 2;
Box[] firstHalf = new Box[mid + theBoxes.length % 2];
```

If `theBoxes` contains 7 elements, then `firstHalf` will contain 4 elements, i.e. 3 + 1, since `mid` equals 3 and `theBoxes.length % 2` equals 1 (one).

If `theBoxes` contains 6 elements (again for example) then `firstHalf` will contain 3 elements, i.e. 3 + 0, since `theBoxes.length / 2` equals 3 and `theBoxes.length % 2` equals 0 (zero).

Now `secondHalf` must contain the remaining elements, i.e.

```java
int secondHalfLength = theBoxes.length - firstHalf.length;
```

The *array copy* operation needs to copy the number of elements in the target array. Since your calculation of the number of elements is wrong, the *array copy* is also wrong. It should be:

```java
System.arraycopy(theBoxes, 0, firstHalf, 0, firstHalf.length);
```

Also the *array copy* for `secondHalf` is wrong. You need to copy elements from `theBoxes` starting at `mid` or `mid + 1` (again, depending on whether `theBoxes` has an even or odd number of elements, respectively) and not from 0 (zero), i.e.

```java
System.arraycopy(theBoxes, mid + theBoxes.length % 2, secondHalf, 0, secondHalfLength);
```

This means that you are sending two, identical (in the case where `theBoxes` contains an even number of elements) or almost identical (in the case where `theBoxes` has an odd number of elements) arrays to method `merge` and that's probably why your resulting array contains the exact, same `Box` in every array element.

Lastly the final two `while` loops, in method `merge`, need to be **after** the first `while` loop and not nested inside it.

Here is the complete code as a [SSCCE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions). You wrote that you can't change class `Box`, so you can simply extract the methods `main`, `merge` and `mergeSort` and write another class for them.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Box implements Comparable<Box> {
    private double width, height, length;

    Box(double w, double h, double l) {
        width = w;
        height = h;
        length = l;
    }

    static void mergeSort(Box[] theBoxes) {
        if (theBoxes.length > 1) {
            int mid = theBoxes.length / 2;
            Box[] firstHalf = new Box[mid + theBoxes.length % 2];
            System.arraycopy(theBoxes, 0, firstHalf, 0, firstHalf.length);
            mergeSort(firstHalf);
            // Merge sort the second half
            int secondHalfLength = theBoxes.length - firstHalf.length;
            Box[] secondHalf = new Box[secondHalfLength];
            System.arraycopy(theBoxes, mid + theBoxes.length % 2, secondHalf, 0, secondHalfLength);
            mergeSort(secondHalf);
            merge(firstHalf, secondHalf, theBoxes);
        }
    }

    static void merge(Box[] list1, Box[] list2, Box[] temp) {
        int current1 = 0;
        int current2 = 0;
        int current3 = 0;
        while (current1 < list1.length && current2 < list2.length) {
            if (list1[current1].compareTo(list2[current2]) <= 0) {
                temp[current3++] = list1[current1++];
            }
            else {
                temp[current3++] = list2[current2++];
            }
        }
        while (current1 < list1.length) {
            temp[current3++] = list1[current1++];
        }
        while (current2 < list2.length) {
            temp[current3++] = list2[current2++];
        }
    }

    private double getVolume() {
        return width * height * length;
    }

    public int compareTo(Box o) {
        double myVol = this.getVolume();
        double thatVol = o.getVolume();
        if (myVol > thatVol)
            return 1;
        else if (myVol < thatVol)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Width: " + width + "\theight: " + height + "\tlength: " + length + "\tVolume: " + getVolume();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box[] boxes = new Box[]{new Box(2, 3, 4),  // volume = 24
                                new Box(2, 2, 3),  // volume = 12
                                new Box(3, 3, 3),  // volume = 27
                                new Box(2, 2, 2),  // volume = 8
                                new Box(4, 4, 1),  // volume = 16
                                new Box(5, 1, 1),  // volume = 5
                                new Box(2, 2, 7)}; // volume = 28
        System.out.println("Original:");
        Arrays.stream(boxes)
              .forEach(System.out::println);
        mergeSort(boxes);
        System.out.println("====================================================================");
        System.out.println("Sorted:");
        Arrays.stream(boxes)
              .forEach(System.out::println);        
    }
}
```

Refer to: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/

When I run the above code, I get the following output:

```
Original:
Width: 2.0  height: 3.0 length: 4.0 Volume: 24.0
Width: 2.0  height: 2.0 length: 3.0 Volume: 12.0
Width: 3.0  height: 3.0 length: 3.0 Volume: 27.0
Width: 2.0  height: 2.0 length: 2.0 Volume: 8.0
Width: 4.0  height: 4.0 length: 1.0 Volume: 16.0
Width: 5.0  height: 1.0 length: 1.0 Volume: 5.0
Width: 2.0  height: 2.0 length: 7.0 Volume: 28.0
====================================================================
Sorted:
Width: 5.0  height: 1.0 length: 1.0 Volume: 5.0
Width: 2.0  height: 2.0 length: 2.0 Volume: 8.0
Width: 2.0  height: 2.0 length: 3.0 Volume: 12.0
Width: 4.0  height: 4.0 length: 1.0 Volume: 16.0
Width: 2.0  height: 3.0 length: 4.0 Volume: 24.0
Width: 3.0  height: 3.0 length: 3.0 Volume: 27.0
Width: 2.0  height: 2.0 length: 7.0 Volume: 28.0
```